# Shopify not getting rates from custom CarrierService

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I'm building a private Shopify app that returns custom shipping rates. Following the [API docs](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/carrierservice), and with some help from [this tutorial](https://www.endertechnology.com/blog/building-a-shopify-carrier-service-app), I created a functional, proof-of-concept that returns some sample shipping rates in my store.

However, that proof-of-concept app is built in PHP, and the final version must be in Ruby on Rails. So I created a Rails app that returns exactly the same content as the PHP app—but for some reason the rates simply don't show up in the Shopify backend.

The only thing I notice that's different is the HTTP headers (I've tried monkeying around with them to match the PHP app, but to no avail). Is there anything obvious I'm missing here?

Here's a comparison of the HTTP response headers:

PHP:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 186
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 16 May 2017 13:00:30 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Rails:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 16 May 2017 12:57:38 GMT
ETag: W/"ce885edaa10636b3b7459dca958f44dd"
Server: nginx
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Request-Id: 54e2575e-c86a-4f44-a315-d0a3fbbc13f9
X-Runtime: 0.616974
```

Again, Shopify handles the PHP response fine, but fails silently on the Rails response. Is there anything in that second (Rails) block that Shopify might be rejecting?

Shopify unfortunately provides no error log or way to debug this type of issue—either they pull the rates from your app or not.

Here is my Rails `rates_controller.rb`:

```
class RatesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    ups_rates = {
      rates: [
        {
          service_name: 'Endertech Overnight',
          service_code: 'ETON',
          total_price: '000',
          currency: 'USD',
          min_delivery_date: (DateTime.now + 1.days).strftime('%F %T %z'),
          max_delivery_date: (DateTime.now + 2.days).strftime('%F %T %z')
        },
        {
          service_name: 'Endertech Regular',
          service_code: 'ETREG',
          total_price: '000',
          currency: 'USD',
          min_delivery_date: (DateTime.now + 3.days).strftime('%F %T %z'),
          max_delivery_date: (DateTime.now + 7.days).strftime('%F %T %z')
        }
      ]
    }

    # Tested returning both application/json (default) or text/html
    #render json: ups_rates
    render body: ups_rates.to_json, content_type: "text/html"
  end

end
```

I suspected maybe Shopify was caching very aggressively, so I've also tried destroying and recreating both my private app and the carrier service, as well as changing the `callback_url`. So far nothing has had any effect.

Comment: Hey Zac, would it be possible for you to post some of your code?

Comment: @JoshBrown Of course! I added the Rails controller code. I'm not sure it will provide much insight though—it seems to be outputting exactly what Shopify is asking for. (Hope I'm wrong!)

Answer (score 2):

After a whole lot of digging, I found the answer: Shopify requests rates via `POST`, but my app was only responding to `GET`.

As a quick fix, I created a static route in `routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post 'customrates', to: 'rates#index'
end
```

In retrospect, this was [clearly stated in the documentation](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/carrierservice#callback-url), I just hadn't noticed (after all, a rate request intuitively *seems* like a `GET` action).

For anyone else encountering this issue, try sending a `POST` via CURL to your `callback_url`, just to verify it's returning what it should:

```
curl -X POST http://yourcallbackurl.com
```